# Consistent work with dates in SSIS without parsing substrings

Tags: date, ssis

At my workplace, we have an ETL workflow in which we have Python code to do most of the heavy lifting for the transformations. The output is a CSV file, and we use SSIS to upload its contents into a data warehouse.

I noticed some inconsistencies in a date column in the data warehouse (type DT_DBDATE), and realized that SSIS has been reading the American-formatted dates from the CSV file wrong.

- if there is only one valid way to interpret the date order, it will interpret it correctly as `mm/dd/yyyy`, so April 20th lands in the database correctly.
- if there are two valid ways to interpret the date order, it will interpret it as `dd/mm/yyyy`, so April 1st becomes January 4th.

This stumped me, because the whole reason to format the dates as `mm/dd/yyyy` in the first place is that it used to cause problems with the German standard of `dd.mm.yyyy`! Also, I cannot imagine a situation where this change of behavior between rows would be the proper way of dealing with a real-world dataset.

I tried researching the question on the Internet, and it seems that the behavior may depend on the localization of the computer on which SSIS is run. This is not an acceptable situation for us, as we have a mixture of computers with different localizations.

I have seen many articles which explain how to read in CSV data with exotic date formats, and parse the substrings, then build up the date "by hand". I find the solution somewhat convoluted, and since I have direct control over the date format which Python outputs, I would very much like a solution where SSIS interprets the date format correctly, regardless of the OS settings of the host machine. For example, being able to give the input date format as a parameter somewhere would be really nice.

Any suggestions how to get the date right without string-manipulation workarounds?

Comment: You should be able to set the matching *Locale* on the Flat File Connection Manager . I tried with your format `MM/dd/yyyy` and Locale = `English (United States)` it was able to distinguish between `01/04/2021` and `04/01/2021` without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the Locale in the connection manager editor, under General

[image]

In this case is English UK but if changed to English US it will interpret the dates as MMDDYYYY